# Visual Studio flutter when I select my Mobile Device It show me this message. I already Installed AS But I now I switched to VS

Tags: flutter, select, emulation, device

What went wrong:
Could not open settings generic class cache for settings file 'C:\flutterproject\flu1\learningdart\android\settings.gradle' (C:\Users\SiliconPc.gradle\caches\6.7\scripts\1fnwrr8g4rohfp291nvlxj5qe).

> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '*BuildScript*' Unsupported class file major version 60

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Can you please run flutter doctor and add the result to your question?

Comment: Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19044.1466], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.

Comment: [√] Chrome - develop for the web
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.66.0)
[√] Connected device (3 available)

Comment: Android Studio seems uninstalled, and you should accept the android licences by running flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: sir, I uninstalled my Andriod. Android Studio was there before that error showed. I had delete and reinstall my java jdk . still it show me this error. I want to attach my physical device to Visual Studio. Visual Studio Code running on web chrome. I have taken the udemy 47 H course . but I have been getting this massage for two or three days. I didn't started my course yet due to this error.

Comment: did you know anything about how to add Android SDK to Visual Studio. Please send me link,If you know any video. thanks batuhand

Comment: You should solve the errors in flutter doctor output before writing any code